# 'rxvt' terminal emulator resets settings after logout

Tags: terminal, urxvt, linux-terminal, terminal-emulator

when ever i logout, rxvt resets to it's out of the box ugly look. Then I have to run the following command to get my settings back.

```
xrdb ~/.Xresourses
```

Do i need to do this every time after I logout.
please help
This is how it looks like after login.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvd1Z.png)

I'm using manjaro linux v-10.1.0 and kernal x86_64 Linux 5.2.11-1-MANJARO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$HOME/.Xresources` file is to contain those of your settings that differ from the defaults, and I assume most Linux distributions DO read/merge settings from this file as X starts.

Make sure you have spelled the filename correctly and maybe also set it be readable by everybody with
`$ chmod 555 $HOME/.Xresources`

Reference:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources

edit: Removed "fix" - and replaced it with the correct solution.

Comment: shouldn't I give a variable name for this alias....and still am I needed to run the command every time before using the terminal (urxvt).

Comment: The `$HOME/.bash_alias` file is just an ordinary text file that Bash interprets "magically" as it starts. So no need to launch it manually and the content doesn't HAVE to be "just" aliases.

Comment: thanks it works after I refrenced .bash_aliases in .bashrc. But still i have to load the terminal once more to load the Xresources file. Anyway thanks for help

Comment: Replaced the info above. Note the misspelled filename!

Comment: Yes I did. 

Comment: Why does it matter if the file is readable by anyone else, and why have execute bits?

Comment: Hmm... thinking about it, it might not be necessary with the executable bit. X is not running in the user context so I take it that at least "group" readability is absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure it's not the X server itself directly reading the user's `.Xresources`. It's probably one of the xsession scripts loading it using `xrdb` which runs as the given user.

Comment: actually I had spelled  ` .Xresources` wrong

Comment: ... and that is often a "hard to catch" error :-)